# Is it possible to add a curly brace in equation in sequence diagram?

Tags: pgf-umlsd

The following code doesn't compile correctly because of the `\{ \}`. When I remove them, it looks normal. Is is possible to have an equation that contains curly braces in a **sequencediagram** block?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{t1}{Thread1}
    \newthread[gray]{t2}{Thread2}
    \mess[1]{t1}{${m_{1}= \{ID, E_{CV}(I)\}}$}{t2}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Error free version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{t1}{Thread1}
    \newthread[gray]{t2}{Thread2}
    \mess[1]{t1}{${m_{1}= ID, E_{CV}(I)}$}{t2}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: error free example]

Alternative example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{t1}{Thread1}
    \newthread[gray]{t2}{Thread2}
    \mess[1]{t1}{$a = \{ b + c \} $}{t2}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Simple example with error]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: What is the `sequencediagram` environment?

Comment: I have updated the code. Is that enough to pass as a Minimal Working Example?
Here's the documentation for the package I used https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-umlsd/pgf-umlsd-manual.pdf

Comment: If I delete `\{\}` I get identical error in your example `! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.`

Comment: please also post the error free code version.

Comment: I added an update to add curly braces in this manner `${...}$`
But you can also try `a = \{ c + d \}`
I will try to add pictures. I'm using overleaf btw (just fyi, not sure how if this info is useful)

Comment: thanks your updated versions are quite different, the error free one has a `{..}` group, and the one generating an error on `\global` is  different error from your original (it has `\{` inside the `{}` group). I still can't aswer your question but at least now seeing the same input and same error that you see:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You could report this to the package maintainers, argument `#3` is used both as typeset text (so can have tex commands such as `\{`) but also internally as a node name (like `\label{...}`) which is much more restricted. This patch makes the string safe before making a node name

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\renewcommand{\mess}[4][0]{%
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}%
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#4)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above]
  {#3};

  \node (\detokenize{#3 from}) at (mess from) {};
  \node (\detokenize{#3 to}) at (mess to) {};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{t1}{Thread1}
    \newthread[gray]{t2}{Thread2}
    \mess[1]{t1}{$\{ m_{1}= ID, E_{CV}(I)\}$}{t2}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution works when I put it with the rest of my code.